# Windows 10 - Can't save files, or execute certain programs unless running programs as administrator

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, windows-installer

So as the title says, I've encountered a user's laptop with a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, where I can't edit documents when running a program normally, such as Word, and more specifically, a program called Mendeley. Also can't run installers normally unless I run as administrator. Running installers normally gave me the error message "Cannot create temp archive". I've tried changing permissions on certain folders, ran integrity checks on the OS as per solutions I've found, and I'm still facing the same problem.

The computer only has the one user, and is not part of a domain.
Any any idea on what to check would be much appreciated, as I've run out of things to check.

Comment: How new is the installation?  It sounds like you should advise the client to just reinstall Windows 10 so everything works without having to be an Administrator.

Comment: The client probably messed up with folder permissions. Check the permissions of the folders you cannot access, regarding the permitted users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in a comment, the client has likely messed up their file permissions and these will need to be corrected.

If the problems are only with files and folders inside their user profile, you can create a new profile, copy the items across, and delete the messed up profile and all its folders.

If the issues are beyond the profile, quite simply you'll need to reimage the computer. It is too difficult to manually correct file permissions and there isn't a mechanism to do this automatically. So, reimaging is the correct method.

Answer (score -2):

A couple things I would try:

1) Run a "gpupdate /force", just in case the computer was once joined to a domain and still has very restrictive group policy restrictions in place.

2) Turn off UAC, turn everything down to the minimum, least restrictive option.

3) Create a new local user and test with that.

I highly suspect this has to do with UAC. If none of the above make any difference I would assume some sort of corruption to the ntfs permissions and would just do another fresh install of Win10.

Comment: Don't mess with UAC. The system is supposed to work normally with it running. If disabling it results in the issues being resolved, the computer should be reimaged.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am a Systems and Network Administrator and what you suggest is very wrong. Don't even start with "but muh Linux" either because Linux does exactly the same thing with root prompts in every major distro. While early iterations were awkward, since Windows 8 UAC has been a good tool in overall security. While you may disable it on a personal computer (I wouldn't) on enterprise computers disabling it is a serious breach of basic principles of security. Disabling it may be an appropriate part of troubleshooting, it is never a fix because that, itself, is a problem.